# C++ accessing a value of vector<int> that is inside class

Tags: c++, windows, class, vector

I have the following class:

```
class clsUnitArrayIndexToUnitID : public CBaseStructure
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> m_content;
        long m_size;
    protected:
        void ProcessTxtLine(string line);
    public:
        clsUnitArrayIndexToUnitID();
        std::vector<int>* Content;
        long Size();
};
```

I would like to access the values from outside the class, for example like this:

```
int iUnitID = m_MyClass.Content()[12];
```

However, C++ tells me that I need to use a point-to function type. 
I am not sure what exactely that means.

Also, if somebody sees any flaw in my code, please tell me.

Comment: `Content` is a pointer to vector. You cannot call it as a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to function (adjust the `const` to your needs)

```
 public:
     const std::vector<int>& Content() const { return m_content; }
```

and use as you described, or dereference a pointer (unsafe?) in either way:

```
m_MyClass.Content->at(12); 
(*m_MyClass.Content).at(12);
(*m_MyClass.Content)[12];
```

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestions, but C++ now tells me "clsUnitArrayIndexToUnitID does not have overloaded element operator '->'.

Comment: That's because the answer places the dereference in the wrong place. `m_MyClass.` was OK; `Content[]` is the problem.

Comment: @elmes Can you please correct your answer? It should be m_MyClass.Content()[12], I think.

Comment: @elmes I am accessing the contents using iUnitID = m_MyClass.Content()[12]; I am not using the asterisk. Is that bad?

Comment: @tmighty Did you declare the public member function (first snippet in my answer) and removed the pointer from your original code? IMO this is the safest way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than exposing the vector, you can give your class indexed access operators:

```
class clsUnitArrayIndexToUnitID : public CBaseStructure
{
 public:
  int& operator[](unsigned int i) {return m_content[i];}
  const int& operator[](unsigned int i) const {return m_content[i];}
....
};
```

then

```
int iUnitID = m_MyClass[12];
```

Comment: Why did you make two overloads of `[]`? How does the program distinguish which one to use? Or did you just show a const variant and a non-const variant?

Comment: @akristmann if the class was used via const (reference), then the secound method would be called, always.

Comment: why return `const int&` over `const int` ?

Comment: @elmes just to keep the same interface as in `std::vector`. An alternative would be to return `int`. There's little point in returning `const int`

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question, you should do this:

```
(*m_MyClass.Content)[12]
```

Or this:

```
m_MyClass.Content->at(12); //note that the semantics is slightly different - at() checks boundaries, [] does not
```

However, the thing you should really do is probably re-think your design. Why does your class have a public data member of type pointer to container? If that will always point to `m_content`, you might as well make `m_content` public and save yourself the hassle.

The general idea behind private data members is to provide semantics-based access, so that your function would publish functions like "insert into vector", "get element from vector" etc. as its semantics dictate. Or, for example, you could provide an read-only accessor function returning `const std::vector<int>&`, and leave modification access to special member functions.

If you provide a wrapper giving direct non-const access, it's hardly a wrapper (it will always have to be directly backed by something).

Of course, the above discussion applies if `Content` is actually a pointer to `m_content` instead of just a pointer to a different vector. But in such case, the class would be even more confusing, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition as follow:

```
 const std::vector<int>* Content() const {
      return &m_content;
 }
```

The first const keyword is not really necessary, but the second one indicates that the method should not and does not modify the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a wrapper method to retrieve the contents or overload operator[] as suggested by juanchopanza.

```
class clsUnitArrayIndexToUnitID : public CBaseStructure
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> m_content;
        long m_size;
    protected:
        void ProcessTxtLine(string line);
    public:
        clsUnitArrayIndexToUnitID();
        //std::vector<int>* Content;

        int GetContent(int index) { 
        int retValue = INVALID_CONTENT
        if(index >=0 && index<m_content.size())
          retValue = m_content[index];
        return retValue;
       }        

       long Size();
};
```

And use it as

```
int iUnitID = m_MyClass.GetContent(12);
```

Comment: I like that, but my application is very much about speed, so any index checking would be bad for me.

Comment: Then just "return m_content[index];" from GetContent(int). With optimization enabled, the compiler will inline GetContent()/operator[] methods. There is no need of any pointers as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can return reference instead of pointer:

```
std::vector<int> m_content(UNITS_MAX_SIZE);

const std::vector<int> &clsUnitsUnitIDToArrayIndex::Content() const
{
    return m_content;
}
```